# Air Flex Uploads URLRequest maximum simultaneous

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to upload to amazon s3 using FileStream and UrlRequest.

But it seems I can only upload 2 files simultaneously.

Is there a reason for this?
How can I work around this?

Also would this affect web service calls to a SOAP web service on the same domain?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is linked to the limit on the number of concurrent HTTP connections per server which is two.

More details check this link :

http://www.openajax.org/runtime/wiki/The_Two_HTTP_Connection_Limit_Issue

Ya I think this may also affect simultaneous HTTP based SOAP Web Service requests also.

Answer (score 0):

It's a concurrent HTTP connection thing. It will vary by service. Though I am surprised Amazon S3 allows only 2. That's fairly draconian.